# Python: 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'screenshot' (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, screenshot, pyautogui

I am trying to take a screenshot with the `pyautogui` module, but keep getting this error

```
>>> image = pyautogui.screenshot()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'screenshot'
```

Is there something I'm missing? The chapter in [Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/) said that as I'm on Windows, I shouldn't need to download anything other than `pyautogui` itself for this to work. Anyone know why this might happen? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am using Anaconda so I already have `Pillow`.

Comment: Try updating the pyautogui using sudo pip install -U pyautogui

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) you need Pillow as well.

Comment: Neglected to mention: I am using Anaconda so already have Pillow. Will edit the question to include that now. Also, my pyautogui is up-to-date.

Comment: Do you have some other script named 'pyautogui.py' somewhere? Like in the current directory?

Comment: @kindall No, I don't believe so. it's possible there is one hiding somewhere but I didn't create one so I don't see any reason one should exist. Why?

Comment: 'cause Python would import that one and if it was one you wrote, it probably wouldn't have a `screenshot()` function in it.

Comment: @ENPM Try help(pyautogui) and see if you can find the attribute 'screenshot'

Comment: @aBiologist It seems that the python executable in charge of the screenshot functions - `screenshotUtil.py` - isn't able to see the `PIL` Anaconda has installed. `screenshotUtil.py` is in `D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda 3\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui` while the `PIL` folder is in `D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda 3\Lib\site-packages`. Do I have to move it somewhere else so it can see it?

Comment: Is it using `import Image` or `from PIL import Image`?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you must run `sudo apt-get install scrot` to use the screenshot features.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyAutoGUI is simply borrowing ImageGrab from PIL/Pillow which you can see  by looking in pyautogui inside of screeenshotUtil.py

```
def _screenshot_win32(imageFilename=None):
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    if imageFilename is not None:
        im.save(imageFilename)
    return im
```

and further down

```
# set the screenshot() function based on the platform running this module
if sys.platform.startswith('java'):
    raise NotImplementedError('Jython is not yet supported by PyAutoGUI.')
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    screenshot = _screenshot_osx
elif sys.platform == 'win32':
    screenshot = _screenshot_win32
    from PIL import ImageGrab
else:
    screenshot = _screenshot_linux

grab = screenshot # for compatibility with Pillow/PIL's ImageGrab module.
```

I had the same trouble as OP, but after realizing the above I used ImageGrab directly. Drawing inspiration from the comment section [here](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/capturing%20screen%20image%20python%20and%20pil%20windows) an answer to OP on windows having pillow installed would look like this:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

time.sleep(5)
box = (1106,657,1166,679) #Upper left and lower right corners
ImageGrab.grab(box).save('box.png') #ImageGrab.grab().save('fullscreen.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyautogui import screenshotUtil

im=screenshotUtil.screenshot()

print im.getpixel((850, 850))
```

I have tried. It's seem to different from the document. to hope this is helpful.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score -1):

Before useing "image = pyautogui.screenshot()", you had to type "import pyautogui" before