# Pyautogui Screenshot Functions return AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I have installed Python 3.4 and Pillow. All the other functions are working related to pyautogui only the screenshots and other image recognition things are not working.

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.locateOnScreen('chrome.PNG')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'locateOnScreen'
```

same results show to screen capture function also.

In windows 7 OS

I have read the below link but non of the results worked for me
[Python: 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'screenshot' (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232282/python-pyautogui-has-no-attribute-screenshot-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Downloading the exact version by mentioning it it in pip.

```
pip install PyAutoGUI-0.9.35
```

or

```
pip install pyautogui==0.9.35
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If having problem with pillow module, first install pillow model through easy installation in command line

```
easy_install Pillow
```

then install the PyAutoGui via

```
pip install PyAutoGUI-0.9.35
```

All in Command Line as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, resolve by uninstalling pyscreeze and pyautogui and reinstall the exact version

1.)
`pip uninstall pyscreeze pyautogui`

2.)
`pip install pyautogui==0.9.35`