# Pyautogui function locateonscreen is giving an attribute error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, attributeerror, pyautogui

I am trying to make implement the pyautogui.LocateOnScreen() funtion in a script however it keeps on giving me this error after i run the script:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.LocateOnScreen('pics\cutwillow1edit.png')

>>>AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'LocateOnScreen'
```

I read another post with the same problem: [Pyautogui Screenshot Functions return AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175395/pyautogui-screenshot-functions-return-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attr)

I tried the solution that worked for that person but to no avail.
I have also tried reinstalling pillow, pyautogui and updating my pip but none of those things have helped  to solve the problem.

I don't know if it matters but I also have opencv-python installed.

I am on Windows 10. I have python version 3.7.2

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions), the function is named `locateOnScreen` (starts with lower-case `L`), not `LocateOnScreen`.

Comment: Oh my God. I am so stupid. This was the problem all along. This fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: It ain't stupid as long as u got the spirit